# filtering factor programming

Tags: indexing, filter

I want to make function, which is filtering odd- index.

```
(filter-idx '(0 1 2 3 4)) => '(1 3)
(filter-idx '(#\a #\b #\c (0 1))) => '(#\b (0 1))
```

So, I made like this, but it doesn't work..

```
(define (filter-idx xs) 
(memf (lambda (x)
(= (remainder x 2) 1))
xs))
```

Comment: What is `(remainder #\a 2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the *indexes* and the *elements* separately. This is one way to do it:

```scm
(define (filter-idx xs)
  (for/list ([i (range (length xs))] ; iterate over indexes of elements
             [x xs]                  ; iterate over elements of list
             #:when (odd? i))        ; filter elements in odd indexes
    x)) ; create a list with only the elements that meet the condition
```

For example:

```scm
(filter-idx '(0 1 2 3 4))
=> '(1 3)
(filter-idx '(#\a #\b #\c (0 1)))
=> '(#\b (0 1))
```